# Simple function to Validate checkboxes in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, ecmascript-6, mapping

I have made a selection limit function which ensures that total checkbox is above min value and under max value, these values were taken from the JSON which the checkboxes are mapped from, now the selection limit works, but I am trying to add validation to show warnings using onblur, but I am not sure how can the same function can be translated into an onblur validation function. for example where if someone unchecks , it shows on the console that you need to select a minimum of 3 until 3 is checked, same logic as selectData().

**Function**

```
  selectData(id, event) {
    let isSelected = event.currentTarget.checked;
    if (isSelected) {
      if (this.state.currentData < this.props.max) {
        this.setState({ currentData: this.state.currentData + 1 });
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.currentTarget.checked = false;
      }
    } else {
      if (this.state.currentData >= this.props.min) {
        this.setState({ currentData: this.state.currentData - 1 });
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.currentTarget.checked = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Full Code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/48o2jo2500?fontsize=14

Comment: How this `onblur` event will be caleed?

Comment: from the input form like <input onblur={function}....

Comment: Can you please give example in code.pen. By comment the line and adding the event which would only `console.log('x')` Then i can try to add functionality you want

Comment: @AlxL I'm sorry, but the full code link does not work. Could you please fix it so that I can see the full component source?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/8212q2pmw0?fontsize=14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your general approach seems like it should work, just need the finesse for actually implementing the error states. A suggestion here though would be to update your `!isSelected && this.state.currentData < this.props.min` condition to allow for less than three to be selected but to display an error state to the user.

```
  ...
    } else {
      if (this.state.currentData >= this.props.min) {
        // this.setState({ currentData: this.state.currentData - 1 });
        // UPDATE:
        this.setState((state) => ({ currentData: state.currentData - 1 }));
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Don't force the box to be selected, show error state instead
        // Disable calls to filtering, sorting, etc. until error resolved
        // event.currentTarget.checked = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

#### Basic Implementation:

- Vanilla JavaScript: https://codepen.io/hollyos/pen/XGqryV
- React: https://codepen.io/hollyos/pen/EMpXdR

Comment: Be aware that `setState` is asynchronous and accessing the previous `currentData` value as you did is not safe. You should write `this.setState((state) => ({ currentData: state.currentData - 1 }));`